# Under what circumstance will websocket stop reading from buffer

Tags: websocket

I have a websocket server. It accepts thousands of connections from clients. Read data from and write data to clients. It will work normally for weeks. But something wrong will happen occasionally, maybe once two weeks. In a very short time, the new clients will establish connections to server and send a protocol immediately. The server side websocket.onOpen() will be invoked, but it fails to read the protocol data from client. And later the client may close the connection. But on the server side, the connections will keep in the state of `CLOSE_WAIT`, but never successfully closed. Via netstat I can see that the `CLOSE_WAIT` connections' read buffer is not empty and keep that value(never be read). So I guess that the server's failing to read data and the close `FIN` package leads to the connection to keep in `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

So I want to know under what circumstance may the websocket fail to read data from reading buffers.

Comment: It seems to me that this might be the server's reactor loop failing... can you still get web pages from the same server (to know if it's limited to websocket connections)?

Comment: Thanks! It is a tomcat game server. We have a connector on port 7000, it is for ws://. Another connector on port 443, it is for wss://.  The two connectors may have different numbers of clients. When the clients fail to communicate with the 7000 ws://, I use netstat seeing that there are about 7000+ CLOSE_WAIT connections on port 7000 and 80+ CLOSE_WAIT connections on port 443. In a very short time, the 443(wss) works normally. But the port 7000 CLOSE_WAIT number keeps growing. When the total connection number reach too 10200(hour  hard limit). The wss:// also fail to work(open too much files)

Comment: you should probably post this as an answer. Seems to that others might find it helpful.